# What's the successor of libgcc1-dbg in Debian 11 and onward

Tags: debian, package-management, debugging

I previously had libgcc1-dbg (and other debug symbol packages) installed on Debian 10 "buster" to get readable stack traces in failure cases or to inspect core files.

It seems, that package does no longer exist. What is the currently preferred method to acquire the debugging symbols under Debian 11 "bullseye", particularly on a system that is not connected to the Internet directly?

**Update:** Thanks to the answer I received: [there is a page detailing the change in the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-dbg` packages have been replaced by `-dbgsym` packages, which are built consistently and available in a separate repository. For Debian 11, you need to add a file, named `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/debug.sources`, containing

```
Types: deb
URIs: http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/
Suites: bullseye-debug
Components: main
```

Then run `apt update`, and you’ll be able to install `libgcc-s1-dbgsym`, which is the successor to `libgcc1-dbg` (`libgcc1` became `libgcc-s1` in Debian 11).

For a disconnected system, you can download [the package file](http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libgcc-s1-dbgsym_10.2.1-6_amd64.deb) on another system, transfer it to the target and install it with `dpkg -i`.